# Process regex matches and non-matches differently

Tags: c#, regex

When the following code is run:

```
string input = "<td>abc</td><td></td><td>abc</td>)";
string pattern = "<td>(abc)?</td>";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    Console.Write(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

If outputs the following text:

```
abcabc
```

That makes sense since the pattern only matches the first and the last `td` elements in the input string.  However, I'd like to change it so that it outputs the following:

```
abc
abc
```

In other words, I'd like it to output a new line when it encounters an empty `td` element.  How could I accomplish this?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev thx :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that like this:

```
string input = "<td>abc</td><td></td><td>abc</td>)";
string pattern = "<td>(abc)?</td>";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    if (match.Groups[1].Success)
        Console.Write(match.Groups[1].Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

By changing your pattern from `<td>(abc)</td>` to `<td>(abc)?</td>`, the `abc` becomes optional.  In other words, either `<td>abc</td>` or `<td></td>` inputs will match.  Since the entire group is optional, you can then use the `Group.Success` property to determine whether or not the capturing group exists in each match.